# issues with mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to use `mysqli_insert_id` in multiple queries, but I keep getting `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`. Below is my code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("Stuff");
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "There was a mistake connecting". mysqli_connect_errno();
                }
        $First=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["FirstName"]);
        $Last=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["LastName"]);
        $Phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Number"]);
        $Product=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Product"]);
        $Quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["Quantity"]);


            if(!empty($_POST["FirstName"]) && !empty($_POST["LastName"])){
                $sql="INSERT INTO Customer(First,Last)
                    VALUE('$First', '$Last')";
                    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
                        if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                            die("ERROR". mysqli_error($con));

                                }
                            }


            if(!empty($_POST["Number"])){
                $sql="INSERT INTO Customer_Number(Customer_ID,Number)
                    VALUE('$id','$Phone')";

                        if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                            die("ERROR". mysqli_error($con));

                                }
                            }

                            if(!empty($_POST["Product"]) && !empty($_POST["Quantity"])){
                                $sql="INSERT INTO Product(Customer_ID,Product,Quantity)
                                      VALUE('$id','$Product','$Quantity')";


                                     if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                            die("ERROR". mysqli_error($con));

                                }else{
                               echo "Special Order Added";
                               }
                            }
                            mysqli_close($con);
                            ?>
```

I've also tried using Last_Insert_ID() as well, but that only works for one query, and then gives me the same error message when I try and add it to the 2nd one.

Comment: Look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call mysqli_insert_id after the mysqli_query

Comment: wow something so simple can make such a big difference lol. thank you.